# Did previous Star Trek series establish Romulan distrust of androids?

Tags: star-trek, romulan, star-trek-picard

In *Star Trek: Picard*, it is introduced that Romulans are fearful of androids. Was this fear ever established in the previous TV series?

Comment: Well, it ain't actually all Romulans.  It's established it's a squirrelly secret cult group.  A secret sub-splinter faction of the Tal Shiar

Comment: According to Picard's housekeeper - she says it is a complete absence of artificial life in Romulan Culture.  Personally I think someone was browsing the wiki entry for DUNE while they were writing the script.

Comment: ....a while ago I promised not to disparage the new shows in comments.

Comment: It's the Zhat Vash (https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Zhat_Vash) who are against all A.I.s, androids, etc

Comment: Given that there's only a handful of known androids in existence, pretty much all traced back to one guy from Earth, one would think that Romulans just don't encounter enough androids for that to even be an issue for them...

Answer (score 16):

No.  This anti-android stuff is new to the Picard show.  See a comparison to TNG's the Defector.

Comment: Romulans in general and Setal (The Defector) are known for not being always truthful. Deliberately over- or misstating the extent of romulan knowledge on the topic of cybernetics would not be completely out of character.

Comment: Perhaps my Romulan is a little rusty, but "I know a host of Romulan cyberneticists who would love to be this close to you" could be translated as "I know a host of heavily armed Romulans who would love to be  this close to you"

Comment: In the light of the most recent episode of Picard I am no longer sure this is a plot hole. He could be referring to the Zhat Vash.